# Проблема с передачей картинки из 1 Аctivity во 2 Аctivity. Приложение крашится

Tags: java, android

```
 `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tt.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:47)`
```

// Activity откуда надо предать

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.images_gridview);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

// 2 Activity куда надо предать

```
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    imaged = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    btnAvatars =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAvatars);
    btnAvatars.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Avatars.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");

    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    imaged = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_imageView);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageAdapter.imageUrls[position]).
            placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imaged);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!emptyValidate(etEmail, etPassword, etConfirmPassword)){
        if(passwordValidate(etPassword, etConfirmPassword)){
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString());

            HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();
            postData.put("email", email);
            postData.put("password", password);

            final PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if(s.contains("ErrorInsert")){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Something went wrong. Data was not inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                }
            });
            task1.execute("https://recognized-vessel.000webhostapp.com/register.php");
        }
        else{  // not equals
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Make sure your password is the same to confirm password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private boolean emptyValidate(EditText etEmail, EditText etPassword, EditText etConfirmPassword){
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirm = etConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
    return (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty() && confirm.isEmpty());
}

private boolean passwordValidate(EditText etPassword, EditText etConfirmPassword){
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirm = etConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
    return (password.equals(confirm));
}
```

// Сам адаптер

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public String[] imageUrls = {
        "https://pp.userapi.com/c830608/v830608758/1dc828/4t_yXClxMH0.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/440H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/441H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/442H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/443H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/444H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/445H.jpg",
        "https://cdn.gratisography.com/photos/446H.jpg"
};

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageUrls.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return imageUrls[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrls[i]).
            placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into((ImageView) view);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать, чтобы исправить ошибку? Где искали ответы и не нашли? В вопросе стоит указывать также, что вы уже предпринимали, для того, чтобы решить вопрос самостоятельно.

Comment: Ошибка связана с тем, что getIntent() у вас null возвращает из которого вы значения пытаетесь получить.

Comment: У него не getIntent возвращает null, в этом случае он не может быть null. getExtras() возвращает null, потому как getExtras() извлекает Bundle, а в этом примере никто никакой Bundle не добавлял в Intent. Автор перепутал 2 варианты передачи данных через Intent: с использованием Bundle и с прямым добавлением Extra данных.

Answer (score -1):

В строке:

```
int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
```

Зачем вы вызываетe getExtras()? Вам нужно у самого intent вызвать getIntExtra("position", 0), где 0 - значение по умолчанию.

[Вот ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) на очень подробный пример.